# Perform simple arithmetic on ng-repeat items and update the controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to angular and will appreciate your help
I need help with the following :
1. I have the following code

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in page ">
                <td class="tdContactsCentered">{{user.name}}<input type="hidden" name="cid" value="{{user.id}}" /></td>
                <td class="tdContactsCentered" >{{user.accountNumber}}</td>
                <td class="tdContactsCentered">{{user.serialNumber}}</td>
                <td class="tdContactsCentered"><input type="text" ng-model="sdate" class="input-small" /> </td>
                <td class="tdContactsCentered"><div class="input-append">
                    <input type="text"  ng-model="ads.value"  class="input-small" />
                </div></td>
                 <td class="tdContactsCentered"><div class="input-append">
                    <input type="text"
                           ng-model ="ads.multipliedByIt"
                           class="input-small"
                           name="expected"
                          />
                </div></td>
```

I set sdate value from my controller and its fine

Below is my angular code.

```
   $scope.ads = {
        value:0,
        multipliedByIt:0
};

var multipliedByIt = function() {
    $scope.ads.multipliedByIt = $scope.ads.value * $scope.sdate;
}


    $scope.$watch('ads.value',multipliedByIt );
```

The issue is, ads.value and ads.multipliedByIt binds to and set same value for all cells/rows in the table, but I want different separate values for the ads.value .

I am not sure I formatted this question appropriate, I hope it is clear enough.

Thank you

Comment: So you want a separate `ads.value` for each `user`?  Right now, `ads` appears to live outside of the `user` being iterated over.

Comment: Yes, thats correct. Please how do I make it reside inside the user. The ADS is meant to be added for each user as fresh property. Thank s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is something like this:

http://codepen.io/robertmesserle/pen/16d97c19d97eb2acf339569565e5dd11?editors=001

Rather than relying on Angular to create local copies of your data for each user, I would recommend doing it yourself:

```
$scope.$watch('page', function (newValue, oldValue) {
  angular.forEach(newValue, function (user) {
    if (!user.ads)   user.ads = angular.extend({}, $scope.ads);
    if (!user.sdate) user.sdate = $scope.sdate;
    user.ads.multipliedByIt = user.ads.value * user.sdate;
  });
}, true);
```

This does a few things:

1. If there is no `ads` object on your user object, it adds one based on `$scope.ads`
2. If there is no `sdate` object on your user object, it copies its value from `$scope`
3. It does the job of your old watcher

The last part works because I passed `true` to the `$watch` method, telling it to do a deep check for changes, which will catch changes to `user.ads.value` as in your previous watcher.

I hope this helps.

---

**Edit**: Adding this in response to your follow-up question.  This should solve your problem:

```
$scope.zoneConfig = function (accountForm) {
  $scope.lastAction = 'create';
  $scope.uri = "/phoenix/protected/users/conf/";
  var uri = $scope.uri;
  angular.forEach($scope.page, function (user, key) {
    var xsrfi = $.param({
      'monthlyContributable' : user.ads.value,
      'expectedAmount': user.ads.multipliedByIt
    });
  });
};
```

The reason it was failing is that there is no `$scope.user` - there is `$scope.page` which contains a series of users.  Since you are iterating over `$scope.page`, I changed `value` to `user` to be a bit more clear, then referenced that directly.

Comment: Please One last thing Robert, When I tried to do HTTP POST using :  $scope.zoneConfig = function(accountForm){
     $scope.lastAction = 'create';
     $scope.uri = "/phoenix/protected/users/conf/";
     
     var uri = $scope.uri;
     angular.forEach($scope.page, function(value,key){
     var xsrfi = $.param({'monthlyContributable' : $scope.user.ads.value, 'expectedAmount': $scope.user.ads.multipliedByIt });    I got user.ads.vlaue is not defined.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for your assistance thus far. I am really grateful. However, the modification above is just posting 0 values for monthlyContributable and expectedAmount. I am really grateful for your time and assistance, I tried not to borther you and solve it on my own but no success.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

When you use `ng-repeat` use `$scope.$parent` to modify values outside child scope.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$scope.ads = {
    value:0,
    multipliedByItself:0
};

var multipliedByIt = function(newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.ads.multipliedByIt = newValue * $scope.sdate;
}

$scope.$watch('ads.value', multipliedByIt );
```